# Getting all logs from Stdout in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, logging, stdout

I run a simple Flask application in a docker container.

To run it i do :

```
docker run --name my_container_name my_image_name
```

The logs are redirected to stdout. So after this command, i see as an output :

```
 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:8080
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

When i want to get the logs with a separate command, i do :

```
docker container logs my_container_name
```

It returns well the logs. Exactly the same output as the output written above.

But if I try to redirect the output to a file :

```
docker container logs my_container_name > mylogfile.log
```

I don't get all the logs! I get only :

```
 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: off
```

Why that ?

Comment: Do some of the logs go to stderr?  Does adding `2>&1` to the end of that command help?

Comment: No it changed nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the container with a dedicated Pseudo-TTY solves the problem.

```
docker run -t --name my_container_name my_image_name
```

The parameter "-t" solved my issue.....But i don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

No need to redirect logs, just use:

```
tail -f `docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' my_container_name`
```

or if you don`t like it , you can try:

```
docker logs -f my_container_name &> my_container.log
```

the trick is the &> which redirects both pipes to the file